# Set ant property when comparing directories

Tags: ant

I have two directories that I need to compare for having same files. I succesfully do this as follows:

```
<fileset dir="d:\test" id="onlyinbar">
    <not>
        <present targetdir="A_DIR"/>
    </not>
</fileset>
<echo>these files are only in bar : ${toString:onlyinbar}</echo>
<fileset dir="A_DIR" id="differentbarfoo">
    <different targetdir="d:\test" ignoreFileTimes="true"/>
</fileset>
<echo>these files are different in bar compared to foo : ${toString:differentbarfoo}</echo>
```

However, I need to issue an other task if either of these  are true. So long the `<condition>` tag does seem to support only file to file comparison and I cannot see how to assign a property within the `<fileset>` tag. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We needed to avoid any third party contribs for this solution. My major problem was the combination of the tags. We knew that our "tests" i.e fileset tags had to be in the condition but didn't know how. The resourcecount though short out the issue:

```
<target name="export-report-icons" description="A description">
    <condition property="test2" else="false">
        <or>
            <resourcecount  when="gt" count="0"  property="flength">
                <fileset dir="d:\test" id="onlyinbar">
                    <present targetdir="DIRs_A" present="srconly"/>
                </fileset>
            </resourcecount>
            <resourcecount  when="gt" count="0"  property="flength">
                <fileset dir="DIR_A" id="differentbarfoo">
                    <different targetdir="d:\test" ignoreFileTimes="true"/>
                </fileset>
            </resourcecount>
        </or>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="copyThis" depends="export-report-icons" if="${test2}">
 ....
</target>
```

So what this does, sets an OR for the case that one of the two filesets succeeds, the counter wraps the fileset resource so that it can be hosted under the condition and the condition has a property true or false depending on ORed counts. The "copy-This" target executes if the ${test2} is true. Please note that if you set id=test2 it will always qualify as true as in this case it checks for value presence.

Answer (score 1):

The [`<union>` set operator](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#union) groups resources from multiple collections into one collection.

Similarly, take a look at `<intersect>` and `<difference>`.

You mention "if", which I assume refers to the `<if>` task from the third-party Ant-Contrib library. Here's an example that echoes if the filesets combined by `<union>` match any files:

```
<if>
    <resourcecount when="gt" count="0">
        <union id="Check">
            <resources refid="onlyinbar"/>
            <resources refid="differentbarfoo"/>
        </union>
    </resourcecount>
    <then>
        <echo>There are differences: ${toString:Check}</echo>
    </then>
</if>
```

Comment: I am not really sure how this will solve the problem. Do you imply to combine the two filesets like: 
<union id="Check">
    <resource refid="onlyinbar"/>
    <resource refid="differentbarfoo"/>
</union>
and then try to create a new task with if?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "issue another task if either of these are true". What is "true" in this case? That there are files in "bar" that aren't in "foo" *OR* there are files in both "bar" and "foo" with the same name, but with different contents?

Comment: Ok, the first fileset will return file names that are missing from A_DIR. The second filset will return files that are different or missing from d:\test. So IF any of those two returns anything I will need to do an echo for example (but only IF).

Comment: I would have preferred to avoid the contrib of the if. However the resourcecount gave me ideas. Check my solution. Thank you very much.